# Hangfire + Crystal Reports email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, hangfire

I'm trying to make it so that we can generate certain reports daily and email them to a bunch of people in a list.

I've tested out Hangfire for recurring jobs and it works well. So that is not an issue. But I'm trying to create a report from my existing Crystal Report file (.rpt). Basically I want to make it so that when this job gets executed, the code would create the report, save it to the disk in a specified path as a PDF, and then I can email it to people as an attachment. So there is no need to be able to see the report on a web page. The idea is to literally just generate the report in the code behind, save it as a PDF, and email it from the code behind after it is saved.

The issue I'm having has to do with the actual generating and saving of the crystal report. *Btw, I'm generating an excel file in the test but I'd change it to PDF for the actual report.* This is what I have so far for generating the report:

```
        string path = @"Save folder relative-path";
        //"report" is declared at the class level and instantiated below.
        report = new ReportDocument();
        report.SetDatabaseLogon(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
        report.Load(Server.MapPath("Relative path to the report"));
        report.SetDataSource(GetDataSet()); //This gets the dataset filled with data for the report

        try
        {
            ExportOptions options = new ExportOptions();

            DiskFileDestinationOptions diskFileOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            ExcelFormatOptions excelOptions = new ExcelFormatOptions();
            diskFileOptions.DiskFileName = path + "Test Report.xls";

            options.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
            options.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Excel;
            options.ExportDestinationOptions = diskFileOptions;
            options.ExportFormatOptions = excelOptions;
            report.Export();

            /*
            This is where I would call a method to email the report to people
            */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error generating report: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

This code is in a method which is being called at Application_Start in the global.asax file of the web application. When I run the application, the job fails and throws this error when I look under the failed jobs in the Hangfire dashboard even though I know the path in my code is correct:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly
>   'App_global.asax.twm32qri, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'App_global.asax.twm32qri, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified. File name: 'App_global.asax.twm32qri,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName)    at System.Type.GetType(String typeName,
>   Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.Deserialize()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

EDIT:

I have another error I'm getting too. This one has something to do
 with loading the report file.

> Failed An exception occurred during performance of the job.
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException
>
> Invalid report file path.
>
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException:
>   Invalid report file path.    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ExceptionThrower.ThrowEngineException(String
>   messageID, EngineExceptionErrorID id)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.EnsureLoadReport()
>   at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(String
>   user, String password)    at Intranet.Global.GenerateReport() in
>   *path*\Global.asax.cs:line 98

Comment: That exception isn't from Crystal...not sure what hangfire is or why you would need to write this in a web app but apparently it's not loading the assembly for global.asax

Comment: @dotjoe Hangfire is for creating background jobs that can be either just fire-and-forget, delayed, or recurring in nature. Mine would be recurring as I would email the report daily.
I understand that the error isn't from crystal. But I'm not sure how to generate and save the report to the disk.

Comment: What error do you get when exporting to disk? Write permissions ok for the target directory?

Comment: @dotjoe I have included the error in the question. It's a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.
Write permissions are in place for sure.

Comment: yes, but that exception is fired before you even get to the Crystal code right??

Comment: @dotjoe actually wait, I'm getting another error also now that I look in the history for this job. I'll edit the post to include that error too in a minute here.

Comment: Maybe remove that try catch so a full exception from the crystal export can bubble up.

Comment: You should set the database logon after you load the report.

Comment: Do you need a logon? Cause it looks like you are "pushing" a dataset into the report...

Comment: @dotjoe I suppose I don't need the logon. I added the dataset afterwards as just having the database logon did not work even though the report file is set up and everything to get the data as long as it gets the logon credentials. I moved the logon code below the Load line though and got this error:

System.Web.HttpException

Server operation is not available in this context.

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server operation is not available in this context.
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path)
   at Intranet.Global.GenerateReport() in *path*\Global.asax.cs:line 98

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80802/discussion-between-dotjoe-and-david-flynn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. I apparently needed to use a CrystalReportViewer object and set the ReportDocument object as its source. The CrystalReportViewer class is in the CrystalDecisions.Web namespace.

```
using (ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument())
{
    using (CrystalReportViewer viewer = new CrystalReportViewer())
    {
        string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"Destination path here");
        report.Load(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"Path to .rpt file here"));
        report.SetDatabaseLogon(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);

        string file = path + "TestReport.xls";

        //These two lines below are important. The report won't generate without them.
        viewer.ReportSource = report;
        viewer.RefreshReport();

        //Just deleting the file if it exists.
        if (File.Exists(file))
            File.Delete(file);

        report.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, diskFileOptions.DiskFileName);
    }
}
```